# Can't use map function after Dispatch Action, React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So i'm doing a API GET request and set the data on reducer, but the component render twice, first before dispatch and another after, the first one is causing map function problem

what can i do to avoid render twice and solve map function problem?

App.js

```
componentDidMount(){
      this.props.carregarLojas();
    }

render(){
   const { lojasTeste } = this.props;
   //rendering 2 times
   console.log(lojasTeste);

   return(
    <div>
        lojasTeste.map((i, index) => (
        <h1>{i.name}</h1>
        ))
    </div>
   )

}

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
    lojasTeste: store.lojaState.lojasTeste
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        carregarLojas: () => {
        dispatch(carregarLojas());
      }
    };
  };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Action.js

```
export const setarLojas = (lojas) =>{
    return {
      type: SETAR_LOJAS,
      data: lojas
    }
  }

  export const carregarLojas = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      return API.get('loja')
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setarLojas(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      })
    }
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState ={
    lojasTeste: {}
}

export const lojaReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch (action.type){
     case SETAR_LOJAS:
      return {
      ...state,
      lojasTeste: action.data 
      }
     default:
       return state;
   }
}
```

Comment: Its ok, to let the render method call twice. Just make sure that on initial render, `lojasTeste` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double render is totally normal: 
Your component render once, then call the `carregarLojas` method which is async. When resolved, the method will update your redux store, which is connected with the props of your component (mapStateToProps). When a prop is updated, it cause automatically a rerender.

Also, for your map problem, you didn't initialized `lojasTeste` as an array, but as an object. You can't use map on an object (cf https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map)